# Get the subdomain as parameter

Tags: react-router

How should one do to use the subdomain as parameter? For example, my URLs might look like this:

```
http://user-a.example.org/media/fmgjksdjknw
http://user-a.example.org/login/wdfjccpnvsd
http://user-a.example.org/login/aeezosdmlkf
```

How can I route my application according to the following pattern?

```
http://{user}.example.org/media/{hash}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is [not possible with react-router.](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/1005)